# getting problems with Me.close

Tags: vb.net

so im trying to make it that when you click an image, it will close the current form. but I'm getting this error.

> Property access must assign to the property or use its value.

and here's the code

```
    Private Sub PictureBox4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles close.Click, close.Click
        Me.close()
        form1.Show()
    End Sub
```

that's everything. thanks!

Comment: Why do you have two times _close.Click, close.Click_?

Comment: This: `close.Click` and this: `Me.close()` look highly suspect when used together.  Do you have a member in your class called `close`?  If so then it's probably obscuring the `Close` method on the parent class.

Comment: David has the right of it. If you have a `PictureBox` whose purpose is to close the form then it should be named `closePictrueBox` to actually describe what it is. If I read just `close`, how would I have any idea that it is even a control, let alone a `PictureBox`? As suggested, you also have the event specified twice in your `Handles` clause. You should also change the name of the mnethod if you have changed the name of the control. That's an example of why you should change control names as soon as you create them. You should not have had three `PictureBoxes` with default names already.

Answer (score 0):

the handles event gets problem. remove close.click,close.clic and Copy the PictureBox1.Click after Handles in your click function

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click